# Validate XML against the XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema

> I'm trying to validate the XML and XML Schema but I'm getting a validation error message "**Cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'tns:submission_type' Is Not Allowed To Appear In Element 'tns:submission'., Line '1', Column '224'.**"
>
> **Note:** The validation error is due to **tns:submission_type="testing"** in the xml file. But I want to use the namespace in the Attribute and it's not working. Any suggestions?

---

> **Schema File (.xsd)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" 
     xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" 
     elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="submission" type="tns:submission"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="submission">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="header" type="tns:header_type" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="detail" type="tns:detail_type" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="error" type="tns:error_type" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="submission_type" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="header_type"></xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="detail_type"></xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="error_type"></xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

> **Xml File (.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:submission tns:submission_type="testing" 
     xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema NewXMLSchema.xsd ">
     <tns:header></tns:header>
     <tns:detail></tns:detail>
     <tns:error></tns:error>
</tns:submission>
```

Comment: I believe adding `attributeFormDefault="qualified"` to your `xsd:schema` definition will allow prefixed attribute names in validated documents.

Comment: Or more specifically you can put `form="qualified"` on this particular attribute to put it in the target namespace, without affecting other attributes.

Comment: Both works. Great !!! Thanks :-D